# Directives using ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Is it possible to add a directive using ng-class? I would like to add ion-scroll directive using ng-class.What I want to acheive is add ion-scroll based on some condition.Does anybody know how is it done.Further does anybody know the code for ion-scroll directive.If I know the code I can figure out someother way.It is something like this that I want to achieve `<div ng-class="ion-scroll">{{x}}</div>`.The ion-scroll is not a class but directive so this would not work.Any idea of how to do this

Comment: Why don't you write `ion-scroll` as custom directive that may be enabled or disabled? You may also write generic directive that may enable/disable other directive by using $compile service - may be a bit diffictult to write.

Comment: You could try making an attribute directive.

Comment: The problem is that when I add a class that has overflow:scroll it is working fine on desktop but not on ipad.On ipad its working fine using ion scroll but it is making eveything scrollable that why I want to add the ion-scroll directive css using ng-class

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
<div class="hasIonScroll" ng-if="someCondition" ion-scroll></div>

<div class="noIonScroll" ng-if="!someCondition"></div>
```

Comment: But the overflow:scroll in HasIonScroll is not wrking on ipad that's why I want to add ion-scroll directive using ng-class